# Can't uninstall Expression Studio 3

Tags: uninstall, microsoft-expression

Regardless of whether I start the uninstall from the Add/Remove Programs applet or from the original setup executable, I always get this exception on startup:

[image]

How can I uninstall Expression Studio 3?

Comment: can you reinstall it first? ensures all the files are in pristine condition (for deletion).

Comment: Starting setup.exe causes the same exact error you are seeing on the screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would delete the files, all reg entries by searching, then disable/remove services and any startup objects using msconfig or regedit :)

Edit :

Before that you should try and advanced uninstaller